# Using scientific notation in for loops

Tags: c++, loops

I've recently come across some code which has a loop of the form

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1e7; i++){
}
```

I question the wisdom of doing this since 1e7 is a floating point type, and will cause `i` to be promoted when evaluating the stopping condition. Should this be of cause for concern?

Comment: One thing in its favour is that you don’t have to count the 0’s in `10000000`, but I prefer to achieve that by writing `10*1000*1000`, expecting constant folding, of course. [Eiffel](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Literals/Integer#Eiffel) rather nicely lets you write `10_000_000`.

Comment: And C++14 lets you write `10'000'000`.

Comment: Or you could define a constant TEN_MILLION

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The **elephant in the room here** is that the range of an `int` *could* be as small as -32767 to +32767, and the behaviour on assigning a larger value than this to such an `int` is *undefined*.

But, as for your main point, indeed it should concern you as it is a *very* bad habit. Things could go wrong as yes, 1e7 is a floating point double type.

The fact that `i` will be converted to a floating point due to type promotion rules is somewhat moot: the real damage is done if there is unexpected *truncation* of the apparent integral literal. By the way of a "proof by example", consider first the loop

```
for (std::uint64_t i = std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max() - 1024; i ++< 18446744073709551615ULL; ){
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

This outputs every consecutive value of `i` in the range, as you'd expect. Note that `std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()` is `18446744073709551615ULL`, which is 1 less than the 64th power of 2. (Here I'm using a slide-like "operator" `++<` which is useful when working with `unsigned` types. Many folk consider `-->` and `++<` as obfuscating but in scientific programming they are common, particularly `-->`.)

Now on my machine, a double is an IEEE754 64 bit floating point. (Such as scheme is particularly good at representing powers of 2 exactly - IEEE754 can represent powers of 2 up to 1022 exactly.) So `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` (the 64th power of 2) can be represented exactly as a double. The nearest representable number before that is `18,446,744,073,709,550,592` (which is 1024 less).

So now let's write the loop as

```
for (std::uint64_t i = std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max() - 1024; i ++< 1.8446744073709551615e19; ){
    std::cout << i << "\n";         
}
```

On my machine that will only output **one** value of `i`: `18,446,744,073,709,550,592` (the number that we've already seen). This proves that `1.8446744073709551615e19` is a floating point type. If the compiler was allowed to treat the literal as an integral type then the output of the two loops would be equivalent.

Comment: I think I follow what you're saying and do get the same output as you do.

Comment: Are there people who write `i ++< foo` rather than `i++ < foo` in earnest? I'd think the only reason to do that was to make a joke.

Comment: Your first `for`-statement is missing a semicolon.

Comment: Not anymore! Thanks @TonyK.

Comment: I thought post-increment was less efficient than pre-increment since it required an extra copy. Granted you probably wouldn't notice either way.

Comment: @cat No, 'moot' (not 'mute') is the proper saying.

Comment: @DanielFischer - I concur - I'm no stranger to scientific computing, and can't say I've come across this idiom before...

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm more amazed that people still use `++` inline at all, personally, and more that's it's actually viewed as normal in some language communities. I've always abhorred mixing variable mutation into the middle of conditionals. =/ Even worse when the last part of the `for` syntax is reserved explicitly for the increment...

Answer (score 14):

It will work, assuming that your `int` is at least 32 bits.

However, if you really want to use exponential notation, you should better define an integer constant outside the loop and use proper casting, like this:

```
const int MAX_INDEX = static_cast<int>(1.0e7);
...
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_INDEX; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Considering this, I'd say it is much better to write

```
const int  MAX_INDEX = 10000000;
```

or if you can use C++14

```
const int  MAX_INDEX = 10'000'000;
```

Comment: Actually the `int` could be as small as a 25 bit 1's or 2's complement type. Granted that's exotic but still possible in standard C++.

Comment: What, 16-bit ints aren't allowed anymore?

Comment: @JDługosz: Sure they are, that's why I wrote "**assuming** that your `int` is at least 32 bits"

Comment: I misread, "the `int` could be as small as 25 bits" as meaning that's what a compiker might throw at you, when @Bathsheba meant that's what it takes for the code to work.

Comment: I wouldn't dwell on this. My remark is little more than a pedantic missive: this is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 10):

`1e7` is a literal of type `double`, and usually `double` is 64-bit  IEEE 754 format with a 52-bit mantissa. Roughly every tenth power of 2 corresponds to a third power of 10, so `double` should be able to represent integers up to at least 10<sup>5*3</sup> = 10<sup>15</sup>, *exactly*. And if `int` is 32-bit then `int` has roughly 10<sup>3*3</sup> = 10<sup>9</sup> as max value (asking Google search it says that "2**31 - 1" = 2 147 483 647, i.e. twice the rough estimate).

So, in practice it's safe on current desktop systems and larger.

But C++ allows `int` to be just 16 bits, and on e.g. an embedded system with that small `int`, one would have Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @IvánPérez: Thanks for that correction, and thanks to Bathsheba for fixing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the intention to loop for a exact integer number of iterations, for example if iterating over exactly all the elements in an array then comparing against a floating point value is maybe not such a good idea, solely for accuracy reasons; since the implicit cast of an integer to float will truncate integers toward zero there's no real danger of out-of-bounds access, it will just abort the loop short.

Now the question is: When do these effects actually kick in? Will your program experience them? The floating point representation usually used these days is IEEE 754. As long as the exponent is 0 a floating point value is essentially an integer. C double precision floats 52 bits for the mantissa, which gives you integer precision to a value of up to 2^52, which is in the order of about 1e15. Without specifying with a suffix `f` that you want a floating point literal to be interpreted single precision the literal will be double precision and the implicit conversion will target that as well. So as long as your loop end condition is less 2^52 it will work *reliably*!

Now one question you have to think about on the x86 architecture is efficiency. The very first 80x87 FPUs came in a different package, and later a different chip and as aresult getting values into the FPU registers is a bit awkward on the x86 assembly level. Depending on what your intentions are it might make the difference in runtime for a realtime application; but that's premature optimization.

*TL;DR: Is it safe to to? Most certainly yes. Will it cause trouble? It could cause numerical problems. Could it invoke undefined behavior? Depends on how you use the loop end condition, but if `i` is used to index an array and for some reason the array length ended up in a floating point variable always truncating toward zero it's not going to cause a logical problem. Is it a smart thing to do? Depends on the application.*